# html select not working

Tags: php, mysql, html, select

Hi 
I am absolutely stuck here, i'm a PHP programmer and i would consider my HTML to be excellent but for some reason i'm stuck on this:

I have a form and it has two select options :

```
<select name="pays">
 <option value ="ireland">Ireland</option>
 <option value ="us">US</option>
</select>
<br>
<select name="carrier">
  <option value="ireland">Irish Network</option>
  <option disabled="disabled"><b>US<b></option>
  <option value="verizon">Verizon</option>
  <option value="sprint">Sprint</option>
  <option value="att">AT&T</option>
  <option value="cellularone">Cellular One</option>
  <option value="nextel">Nextel</option>
  </select>
```

My PHP file is this:

```
$country= $_POST['pays'];
$carrier= $_POST['carrier'];
```

....

```
$sql="INSERT INTO members (cname, cnumber, country, carrier)
VALUES ('$name', '$number', '$country', '$carrier')";
```

The strange thing is that the values $name and $number work fine (they are input fields in the form aswell) but the two select options are empty. I've echoed out the $country and $carrier but they're blank, making me think there is a problem with the form.

Any ideas??

P.S no errors come up

P.P.S if you don't speak french, pays=country in french

Thanks 
Niall

Comment: show your actual code of PHP file. May your variable got overwritten

Comment: Its not much for proper debugging, but maybe check first if the post-variables you want to use are actually there at all:  print_r($_post);

Comment: You can turn on the debug `error_reporting(E_ALL);` since you didn't use any silly isset. Should the fields not be present you get a hint about that. If so, it might be that the select fields reside outside of the form(?)

Comment: are you sure you've got method="post"?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` in your PHP file and check if the values come through.

Comment: Like I said I don't think the POST variables come through

Comment: Is register_globals turned ON in your php.ini file - just curious?

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind, print_r($_POST) and see if the values are in post.

Are the select boxes inside the  tag, stating the obvious but could be the issue?

Comment: POST your HTML here might help us help :)

Answer (score 0):

The form looks OK. Are you performing any validation on the $country and $carrier variables? If you are (for example) running mysql_real_escape before connecting to the database then that can cause the problem you describe, where the variables are blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option disabled="disabled"><b>US<b></option>
```

is not valid.. should be

```
<option disabled="disabled"><b>US</b></option>
```

Comment: This is irrelevant I don't use <b> </b>

Comment: Oh wait sorry but that wouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> $sql= sprintf("INSERT INTO members
>   (cname, cnumber, country, carrier)
>   VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", 
>       $name, 
>       $number, 
>       $country, 
>       $carrier );

That's because when you exectue an SQL query with single quotes inside, it will not evaluate the variable, it will literally use the value inside the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the right method (post)? If you don't specify `$_GET` will be used. Also to get both "pays" and "carrier" in one form-post they should both be in the same `<form>` see below example code:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="pays">...</select>
    <select name="carrier">...</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDit Comment : a) I realsed that this is way off topic and b) my code includes CSS for the fieldset. I do apologise for the red herring. ianm

I have a PHP CSS, and HTML application online at www.toursbw.net  . Using the DEMO selection gains access to the FULL SYSTEM.

When I run this using my Samsung Android Smartphone my selection boxes/fields display the first line as blank BUT when the select downarrow is touched the selection options are displayed in the same way as the keyboard and all works fine. It needs to be triggered by the down arrow.

**select_book :**

```
function select_book($sid = 0, $debug = false) {

$db = "  ";
$sql = "select confirmed, bkname, bkid, custid, reftype
        from t_book order by confirmed, bkname, bkid"; // id to sequence dups
if ($debug) { echo "<br />fb1030 sql: $sql |<br />"; show_session(); }    
$arr = tdbquery( $sql );
$src =  $_SESSION['rowdb'];
if ($src > 0) {      
     $db .= "<fieldset>     
        <legend>Select a Booking by NAME ($src):</legend>
        --- Sequence is Unconfirmed (Ux) first then Confirmed (Cx). Where 
        x is N for NORMAL I for Person Of Interest C for CLIENT and S for SUBBY.<br />        
        <label for=\"controlinfo\">Booking Ref. Name :</label>         
        <select class=\"formSelect\" name=\"byname\" size=\"10\" >           
           ";
     while ($recs = mysqli_fetch_array($arr)) {
         $id = $recs[bkid]; 

         $st = "("; 
         if ($recs[confirmed] > 0) { $st .= "C"; } else { $st .= "U";};  
         if ($recs[reftype] == 1) { $st .= "I)";}
         elseif ($recs[reftype] == 2) { $st .= "C)";} 
         elseif ($recs[reftype] == 3) { $st .= "S)";} 
         else { $st .= "N)";} 

         $db .= "<option value=\"$id\" ";
         if ($id == $sid )  {                   
            $db .=  " selected > $st -- $recs[bkname] -- (ID:$recs[bkid]) </option>";  
         } else {     
            $db .=  "> $st -- $recs[bkname] -- (ID:$recs[bkid]) </option>";}
         }
    $db .= "
    </select>
    </fieldset>  ";         
} else {
        $db .= "<h4>fb1058 There are no bookings available: </h4>
        ";}
return $db;
}  // end select_book
```

This is the code that produces the selection box / field.
(The $debug code is set ON externally and showed no abnormalities when run on the Smartphoe.)

Hope this is of some use, ianm

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_POST['name'] to get value from post method.

```
 <?php
if($_POST){
print_r($_POST);
echo "<br/>";
echo $_POST['pays'];
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name="pays">
  <option value ="ireland">Ireland</option>
  <option value ="us">US</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope it helps you!!!